# GitLab api: how am i able the get the list of projects using gitlab api?

Tags: api, gitlab-api

i was trying to get the list of projects in my gitlab using Git api. for that i was following Git lab api instruction.

they said i can access the list of project by this link: 
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?access_token=some_token.

but unfortunately with the above link i got bunch of information, which is not mine at all. i got the information which is owned by other users.

In that case how am i able the get my own projects information?

Nevertheless, the respond JSON has so many attribute. is there anyway that i can achieve the attribute according to my desire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `owned=true` to get only project which you are owner and `simple=true` to have limited field, check [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) :

https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?access_token=some_token&owned=true&simple=true

Comment: i have accepted your answer. Can you please tell, if i want to reduce the amount of attribute how can i achieve that? let say i just want to return all the project name and their id. how can i achieve that? @bertrand-martel

Comment: @Kazi you can't select the field you want using rest API, but the good news is that gitlab will have [graphql support](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#road-to-graphql) in a near future, so you can stick with rest api for now and move to graphql when it's released